# Android Facebook share says "Not Found"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am trying to provide a share on facebook feature with a link to google play. Its working well except for 1 issue. The main title on the share page says "Not Found"

Here's my code:

```
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this,
            FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
        // Publish the post using the Share Dialog
        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setDescription(getString(R.string.facebook_description))
                .setPicture(getString(R.string.facebook_picture))
                .setLink(getString(R.string.url_google_play) + getPackageName())
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());

    }
```

And here's the result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ylx5zo265yjg66i/Screenshot_2014-05-14-16-35-04.png

I first thought I needed to setCaption, but this seems to break things - I don't get the link or icon at all!

Have I missed something? I have been through the docs over and over.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

**.setApplicationName("") .setName("test:")**

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                    .setApplicationName("<app name>")
                    .setName("test:")
                    .setCaption(caption)

                    .setDescription(getString(R.string.facebook_description))
                    .setPicture(getString(R.string.facebook_picture))
                    .setLink(getString(R.string.url_google_play) + getPackageName())
                    .build();
```